DC Voltage Doubler
I found this schematic in a youtube video:

Why the load capacitor is charging to 15 volts?
Reference: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-6OoOcfXcpo

This is a variation of a voltage doubler. You can think of it in being in two states:

Cap input low: cap charges to +10V via upper diode
Cap input high: cap output goes to +15V, transfers current to output cap via lower diode.

Try a simulation here

The 5V swing 'stacks' on top of the 10V to get a bit less than 15V (it's less due to the diode forward voltage drop.) If you change the DC supply to 5V you will get a bit less than 10V.

Why the resistor is needed here?

It isn’t needed per se, but shows what to expect in a real world use case with some kind of a load.

It will be less than 15V because of the diodes and the load. But in theory, with no load and ideal diodes, the output cap will approach 15V.
This is because when the sine generator is low (0V), 10V worth of potential forms across the coupling cap. When the sine generator goes high (5V), it sums with the previously charged coupling cap of 10V simply because the cap and the sine generator are in series.
Since the potential of Sine Generator (+5V) + coupling cap (+10V) is greater than the output cap, the lower diode is forward biased and charge moves from the coupling cap to the output cap until the potentials are equal (15V). In which case, no addition current will flow. This whole circuit is called a charge pump.

And when the signal is low (0 V), then no current will flow through the diodes, because there is no potential difference, the diodes are reversed bias. Correct?

@TRAXX That is correct. Current only flows when the voltage tends to be greater on the Anode side vs the Cathode side of the respective diode.

This is actually a VERY simple circuit to understand if you know what you are looking at.
The sine wave source voltage is "swinging" up and down between 0V and +5V.
We can represent its two extremes with a 5V battery and an SPDT (single pole, double throw) switch.
The low extreme when the sine wave voltage swings to zero is represented in the schematic below.
It is the same as if you connect the left side of the C1 capacitor to the ground (which is at zero volts).
We will assume that the diodes are ideal (no forward voltage drop).
The voltage from the supply battery BAT1 is passed through the diodes D1 and D2 to both capacitors, charging them to +10V.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
The high extreme when the positive peak of the sine wave source reaches +5V is represented in the schematic below.
You can now see that the left side of C1 is raised to +5V, and since the capacitor was previously charged to +10V by the supply battery B1, its 10V is added to the +5V from the sine wave source.
This now results in +15V on the right side of C1 in reference to the ground.
The diode D1 is now reverse biased and is blocking the current from C1 going back to the battery B1.
The diode D2 is still forward biased and passes the +15V to the output capacitor C2.

simulate this circuit
The above action keeps repeating as the sine wave source voltage keeps oscillating, thus supplying the current that is taken away by a load connected across the output capacitor.

With both capacitors initially discharged, and the the oscillator (V1 below) has 0V potential difference, the circuit looks like this:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
That will very quickly charge both capacitors with 10V.
Then, when the oscillator voltage rises to 5V, the circuit becomes this:

simulate this circuit
Since C2 is charged to 10V, when its lower end, node Y, is "lifted" by 5V, so too is its top end, node X, which becomes +15V.
Being higher than the +10V at the top of C1, current flows down through C1, charging it up a little, increasing the voltage across it. In other words, charge is transferred from C2 to C1, increasing C1's voltage a little. Eventually, after a few oscillator cycles, C1 will have charged to 15V, at which point there's no longer any potential difference remaining (when the oscillator voltage rises) to cause current to flow, and no further charge is transferred.

Looking for the common idea
You have proposed a nearly identical circuit for voltage multiplication in your Square wave DC voltage doubler, except it uses a square wave input. I have conducted a thorough analysis comparing it to the classic voltage doubler, and made the assumption that it was probably created to work with a unipolar input voltage. This belief of mine was strengthened after I got acquainted with the present circuit. Initially, I thought of writing the same detailed answer adapted for it. But I came to the conclusion that it would be much more interesting to compare the three circuits - on the one hand, the classic one, and on the other hand, your two, showing the meaning of each circuit solution. The explanation surfaced in my mind and I started to make the present answer.
I came to the conclusion that the circuits differ only in the first state when the capacitor C1 is charged;  that is why I only drew it.
Voltage doubler
In this classic circuit solution, the input AC voltage source is bipolar. Its negative half-wave voltage charges the capacitor C1, and then this "copy" is added to the positive half-wave. As a result, a doubled voltage is obtained - 5 V + 5 V = 10 V.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

In the conceptual circuit diagram, when the input voltage is negative (Vin-), switch SW1 is closed and switch SW2 is open. This allows battery B1 to be charged up to the same negative peak voltage level (5 V) as the incoming AC supply.

simulate this circuit
Voltage "summers"

Why the load capacitor is charging to 15 volts?

In these circuit solutions (aka charge pump), the input AC voltage source is unipolar (0 V and 5 V). But now its zero voltage state cannot charge C1. That is why, we connect another but constant 10 V Vcc voltage source that charges C1. Then this "10 V Vcc copy" is added to the 5 V positive half-wave. As a result, a higher (Vin + Vcc = 5 + 10 = 15 V) voltage is obtained. However, here it can be of arbitrary value. So the circuit is not necessarily a doubler; it is more of a summer.
As can be seen, the only difference between the two circuit solutions is in the input voltage source.
With square wave input voltage
In your other question, it was square wave...

simulate this circuit


simulate this circuit
With sine wave input voltage
... while in this one it is sinusoidal.

simulate this circuit


simulate this circuit
But the result is the same: 5 V + 10 V = 15 V.
Conclusions

In the classic voltage doubler, the input voltage is bipolar AC. The negative half wave is stored by a capacitor and then added to the positive one. In this way, the voltage that is added is the same and a doubled voltage is obtained; hence the name "doubler" .
In the OP's circuits, the input voltage is unipolar ("lifted") AC. The voltage of another (DC) voltage source is stored by the capacitor and then added to the positive half wave. Thus, the voltage that is added can have an arbitrary value.

