Square wave DC voltage doubler
Can someone can explain why the load should have a high impedance here?

ref: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QT2whZ-414M

TRAXX, The author of that video clearly doesn't fully understand the circuit. That's obvious from how he describes part of the cycle in the video. He's also getting load voltage values that are lower than should be expected with a 50 k load on it and using his two 4.7 uF caps. It's wrong by enough that he should look closer at his layout. (Might be the use of solderless breadboards? Or something else.)

How does the circuit really work? Here is what I am thinking. Why is the cap Co charging/discharging? For example. If the signal is low, then Co is charging into the chip and Cl is also charging. There is 0 V voltage at the left plate of the cap and a positive supply voltage at the right plate. That's why the cap is charging to the supply voltage. If the signal is high, than Co is discharging, but why? Cl is almost doubling its voltage.  What are the voltage potentials at all important nodes here?
Thanks for help!

The Co capacitor is specified to transfer power. The Cl capacitor controls output ripple voltage. Both are affected by the chosen frequency and other similar factors. But the two capacitors are not entirely driven by all the same factors -- they each possess some differences in design. Also, the video author was completely wrong in talking about how there are "two voltage" sources, one from the Co and one from the diode, in explaining the doubling effect. The diode is actually off during that phase and doesn't contribute at all. Also, the video author's results seem a bit off.

I am confused now

When I get a moment I can try to explain. The only way you can know if my explanation is correct is if it makes accurate, quantitative predictions over a range of circumstances. Quantitative prediction is everything. I can do that. But not right now. Going to sleep.

Thanks, you are the best.

How about this circuit?
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/729251/dc-voltage-doubler
It's similar. Is the explanation there also wrong?

Does it predict quantitative values for varying loads, frequencies, source impedances, and types of diodes? Does it explain the different roles played by the two caps? Is it scaleable to both half and full Dickson layouts, and more stages? If not, ....

@TRAXX Did you check MY answer?

Simply because the load can only draw as much current over a switching period as there is charge in the capacitors.
And these capacitors have to be charged and discharged, so there's a limit to how much charge can be on them.
If you need a higher voltage supply, there's significantly better step-up converters than a diode/capacitor voltage doubler.

Basic idea
The fundamental principle of a voltage doubler is to replicate the voltage of a voltage source in a storage element (capacitor) and then add it in series. This results in a doubled voltage, which is stored in another capacitor. Since the load consumes current and discharges the capacitor, this process is repeated periodically. So, a voltage doubler is essentially a "voltage-doubling rectifier".
Implementation
To simplify the understanding of these circuits, which normally use capacitors and diodes, we can replace them with more familiar components. Let's imagine capacitors as rechargeable batteries and diodes as simple on/off switches. Also, instead of using a single AC power source, let's consider two DC power sources (one positive, one negative).
Classic voltage doubler
Traditionally, this circuit is powered from a single alternating current voltage source.
Conceptual circuit
Vin = -10 V: When the input voltage is negative (Vin-), switch SW1 is closed and switch SW2 is open. This allows battery B1 to be charged up to the same peak voltage level (10 V) as the incoming AC supply.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Vin = 10 V: When the input voltage is positive (Vin+), SW1 is open and SW2 is closed. The battery B2 is charged to the sum of the voltages Vin+ and VB1, which is twice the value of Vin+; hence the name "voltage doubler".

simulate this circuit
Real circuit
Usually, diodes are used as switches.

simulate this circuit
As you can see, the capacitors gradually increase their charge (voltage) over several cycles of the input voltage.

New voltage doubler
Comparison
Your circuit differs from the classical one in several ways. Firstly, the input source Vin is unipolar, ranging from 0 V to 10 V, whereas the classical circuit employs a bipolar source that swings between -10 V and 10 V. Additionally, the anode of diode D1 is "lifted"  by the peak value (10 V) of the input voltage.
Conceptual circuit
Vin = 0 V: Unlike the classical circuit, here battery B1 is charged at zero input voltage because its positive terminal is lifted by Vcc (by 10 V).

simulate this circuit
Vin = 10 V: When the input voltage is positive (Vin+), SW1 is open and SW2 is closed. The battery B2 is charged to the sum of the voltages Vin+ and VB1, which is twice the value of Vin+.

simulate this circuit
Real circuit
As you can see, a 10 V "shifting" voltage source Vcc has been added.

simulate this circuit
Impact of the load

Can someone can explain why the load should have a high impedance here?

No load: When there is no load connected or it is too small, the capacitors retain their charge, and consequently, their voltage. It is interesting that the capacitor C2 starts charging from 10 V, not from 0 V as in the classic case.

Varying load: However, as the load increases (its resistance decreases - 10 kΩ, 2 kΩ , etc.), capacitors discharge more rapidly, causing a decrease in voltage and ripple in the rectifier output.

That is why the load must have a high resistance.
Conclusions

In the classic voltage doubler, the input voltage is bipolar AC. The negative half wave is stored by a capacitor and then added to the positive one. In this way, the voltage that is added is the same and a doubled voltage is obtained; hence the name "doubler".

In the OP's circuit, the input voltage is unipolar ("lifted") square wave AC. The voltage of another (DC) voltage source is stored by the capacitor and then added to the positive half wave. Thus, the voltage that is added can have an arbitrary value.

It can be assumed that the OP's circuit is designed to function with a single-polarity input voltage (so it can be controlled directly by a 555 timer) and a variable amount of added voltage.



@TRAXX, I have finished the simulations and will add explanations later; I cannot do it now. Please review the results and feel free to ask any questions you may have.

Thanks, you are the best.

This circuit is similar here:
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/729251/dc-voltage-doubler
Also wrong explanations?

@TRAXX, Thank you, I'll take a look at that as well once I've finished explaining this circuit. I would have preferred to post my response in parts and have you provide feedback on each part (creating a more interactive discussion). Unfortunately, this platform doesn't allow for that, requiring the entire answer to be submitted at once. This constraint significantly hinders my ability to provide a thorough explanation, but I'll have to comply with the platform's rules.

@Circuitfantasist You put a lot of effort in text formatting; the look of it alone makes it fit for a textbook. Your explanations are also fit for a textbook, done in a scholarly way, step by step, to lead the reader closer and closer to the full solution. At first, it seemed complex, but I gave it another try and read it thoroughly. It was easy to navigate with the great format. You kept it short, simple and clear. The only thing that makes it confusing is using batteries instead of capacitors, because not all batteries can be charged and not quickly, and capacitors are easy to understand.

@Edin Fifić, Thank you for your response! Like everything else, there are also disadvantages, such as a larger volume. A shorter option would be to write a short text within the schematic. The advantages of batteries, in my opinion, are that they are more primary than capacitors (they are found in everyday life) and have a marked polarity. In these moments, when taking "snapshots" of the circuit, they may not be rechargeable. But the main reason for using them is that the simulator does not have the ability to set an initial voltage value for the capacitors (at least I don't know of such).

@Circuitfantasist "But the main reason for using them is that the simulator does not have the ability to set an initial voltage value for the capacitors".  Oh, now I see why you use them, makes sense.

C0 has an impedance to electron flow (current).  That impedance is inversely proportional to the frequency of the signal going through it.
Z = 1 / (2 x pi x f x c)
Z = impedance in ohms
f = frequency in hertz
c = capacitance in farads
Z and Rl form a 2-element voltage divider.  If Z equals Rl, the peak voltage across Rl will be 1/2 the 555 output voltage, minus the D1 and D2 Vf drops.  Thus, for any given frequency and c value, a higher value Rl means a higher peak voltage across it.
And for any given value of c and Rl, a higher switching frequency yields a higher voltage across Rl.  This relationship does not go up to very high frequencies, because other capacitor properties can change.

To explain DC circuits and square wave signals using impedance seems strange to me…

I don't understand your comment.  What part of the OP schematic is a DC circuit?

At the output of a circuit there is a charged capacitor and a load connected to it.  I would not explain this coupling through the abstract concept of impedance.  But I don't want to argue;  if you like it, use it.  I just shared my point of view.

A square wave is not really a "wave", but a series of ON and OFF or HIGH and LOW states.
So, what you are getting at the output of a square wave generator like the 555 IC here would ideally be a voltage swing from 0V to the positive supply voltage value.
Below is a schematic and an explanation how a square wave voltage doubler works (I will assume ideal diodes to make it easier to understand):
The switch imitates a square wave generator output by switching the left side of the capacitor C1 between 0V and the positive supply voltage of 10V.
The schematic below shows the moment when the square wave output is LOW.
The left side of the capacitor C1 is at 0V, and the right side of it charges up to the supply voltage of +10V through the diode D1.
The output capacitor C2 is also charged up to the same +10V through the diode D2.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Now we move the switch to the positive side of the power supply, as in the schematic below.
The left side of C1 is now "lifted up" to +10V.
The 10V to which the C1 was previously charged is still there.
This 10V across C1 gets added to the +10V on its left side, effectively doubling it and making it +20V on its right side.
The +20V is blocked by the now reverse biased diode D1 from going back to the +10V side, while it is forwarded through the still forward-biased diode D2 to the output capacitor C2.

simulate this circuit
Regarding your question why should the output impedance be relatively high, that is typically for two reasons: to reduce the output voltage ripple, and because less than half of the already low output current of the 555 is now actually available.

Edin Fifić, the circuit operation is very well explained; I fully agree! BTW, In CircuitLab library there are "ideal" diodes; I prefer to use them in conceptual schematics because they simplify them. The SPDT switch really gives a better idea of a complementary stage than a voltage source. One recommendation of mine is that it is good for a schematic to be brought to life through simulation. However, where did the OP go? What happened to them?
